# JS: examples of class usage in UIs?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning es6 classes and I'm having a hard time seeing how that would be used in the view.  Like if I had a `User` class, it seems like it'd be more a backend concern:

```
class User {
   constructor(name, age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
   }

   giveIntro() {
       return 'Hi, I am ' + this.name + ' and I am ' + this.age + ' years old'
   }
}
```

1. Why would user creation happen on the frontend rather than giving the data to a backend to store & save where it could persist?
2. How could this 'feed' the UI the data it needs to make a list of users?

Comment: As for #2, _"How could this 'feed' the UI the data it needs to make a list of users?"_, you could have a form in the UI. Said form could marshal that data into a constructor. That object could calculate something, and serialize that data before sending it off to the server.

Comment: Your `User` class would be used in the model, not in the view.

Comment: @Bergi: We do use such classes in React and in view itself :) Well React doesn't follow MVC pattern

Comment: @Bergi is there an example of what that would look like?  It just seems abstract to me when I try to visualize that as a frontend concern

Comment: @RicardoAlvveroa Why do you think that it would be used only in the frontend? JS is ubiquitous. And in case of SPAs, a lot of the application logic might run on the client. So if you can see how this `class` is useful in general, there's your answer.

Comment: @Bergi right, makes sense.  I guess I am thinking about it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class as a model on the front-end. It will be used to store data that can then be used later when rendering.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  giveIntro() {
    return `Hi, my name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} years old.`
  }
}

const users = [];

const addUser = (e) => {
  const form = e.target;
  const name = form.elements.name.value;
  const age  = form.elements.age.value;
  const user = new User(name, isFinite(age) ? age : undefined);
  users.push(user);
  form.reset();
  renderUsers();
};

const renderUsers = () => {
  const results = document.querySelector('.results');
  const oldList = results.querySelector('ul');
  if (oldList) {
    results.removeChild(oldList);
  }
  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  users.forEach(user => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = user.giveIntro();
    list.append(item);
  });
  results.append(list);
};

const userForm = document.forms['person'];

userForm.elements.name.value = 'John Doe';
userForm.elements.age.value = 42;

userForm.addEventListener('submit', addUser);
```

```css
form div > label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form name="person" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" min="1" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr />
<h2>Results</h2>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: this was exactly what I need to wrap my head around it, thank you.   So normally when I have a form on the UI, I just put those data pieces into an object and push that object to array....this just extracts that step of "putting that data into an object" as a class, right?

Comment: @RicardoAlvveroa It is a way to keep objects in memory. You can then load those objects from a server or send the ones you have to the server. You just serialize them as JSON and have a corresponding POJO on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you one example. If you see we have many Javascript libraries; Let's take an example of ReactJS.

Where we store data on the front-end in a variable called `state`. We use the class based components in React which has it's state within and then render the data in the Front-End itself.

Also, note that getting user data from back-end every time is an overkill. So, we initially take all the back-end data using an API call and use it on the front end itself so that performance improves a lot.

Comment: "We use the class based components in React" — Function components with the `useState` hook are more common these days.

Comment: I mean we have used classes a lot before 16.8 came and still facebook has those classes everywhere (for instance)